# How to have dlls copied to lib folder and exe to bin folder and make it still work?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ideally, we would like our automated build(using jenkins to call a build.bat which calls msbuild right now) to end up with a zip file with these folders

- product/bin - contains exe files to start the program
- product/lib - contains dll files needed by the exe
- product/conf - contains configuration files

How to get Visual Studio to put all the files in the correct place such that the exe will still work correctly as right now the dlls seem to have to be in the same folder for it to work :( :(.  and I do not want ot install dlls in the GAC.  I just want the above structure so a user can unzip and run the program immediately.

I want this to work in visual studio when I run in debug mode and when I run the build outside visual studio as well (I can add zipping it all up easily enough in the build.bat if I have to).

thanks,
dean

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and call `Assembly.Load` with a path to the `lib` directory.

Note that you must add the handler before JITting any methods or classes that use types from the assemblies you need to load.

Comment: but visual studio is still putting all the dlls in one folder.  I need visual studio to put those dlls in a lib folder and exe in a bin folder otherwise when I run in debug mode, it still does not work since lib does not exist.

Comment: uhm, what if it asks for other libraries I don't know about?  Won't adding lib in front of everyone break those libraries from loading then? OR does it only ask me about my libraries?

Comment: @DeanHiller: This event will fire for all assemblies loaded in your AppDomain.  It's up to you to figure out where the DLLs are.  You can also do nothing and let .Net resolve it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Probing" in your app.config file.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx
I just tested it, and it works.